# Why does C++ not support concise code for constant string concatenation at compile time without using macros?

Tags: c++

I have a code base which has a lot of text manipulation in it. It reads very nicely using C++ macro's facility (space operator?) which *neatly* concatenates constant strings.

I would like to avoid using macros since they have global effect and start using namespaces to good effect.

Unfortunately I cannot find any way to replicate the current readability of the cpp code without using macros and I doubt there is any way to achieve what I would like.

Hence my question.

abc.h

```
#define snippet1 "some text1"
#define snippet2 "some text2"
```

xyz.cpp

```
std::string s = "some text" snippet1 "some more" snippet2;
```

Addendum:
The code can *neatly* be handled at run time with std::string

```
using namespace std::string_literals;
const auto snippet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyyz"s;
auto s = "some text"s + snippet + "some more"s;
```

but this grossly inefficient due to std::string being heap allocated.
My question is why does C++ not seem to have any efficient way for managing constant strings at compile time ... other than the macros will their attendant scope problems.

Comment: Are you having a *measurable* performance problem from concatenating strings?

Comment: You can probably use `constexpr` depends what you're trying to do, show a [mre]

Comment: You should check [real string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s) in favor of c-style const char arrays.

Comment: std::string is sadly not constexpr and no sign of becoming so in the future even though SSO could in principle be constexpr. What I am trying to do is written in my note. Concise code for constant char* strings.

Comment: @Abazoo `std::string` is constexpr-friendly since C++20. A variable of type `std::string` cannot however be `constexpr` at all, so it shouldn't matter for the example you are showing where `s` is already unusable in constant expressions. However the statement you are showing would work as _part_ of a constant expression evaluation with `operator+` applied to individual `std::string` just fine in C++20.

Comment: const char* snippet = "asdhcakjhsdg";
std::string s = "some text" + snippet + "some more";
Doesnt compile.

Comment: @Abazoo It should be `std::string snippet` (maybe with added `const`) and then it will.

Comment: Of course the whole job can be done at runtime with std::string but that is not my q. My question is why can C++ not do simple string management efficiently at compile time without using macros with all their inherent problems of scope.

Comment: auto snippet = "abc"s ..... auto s = "abc"s + snippet + "xyz"s; makes for nice readable code but is grossly inefficient since all the absolutely constant string manipulation is done at runtime and on the heap which is just ridiculous when everything is constant in fact. I find it strange that C++ requires use of macros for constant strings.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenating string literals at compile-time assuming C++20. No run-time heap allocation except the one for `s`:

```
template<std::size_t... Ns>
consteval auto strlit_cat(const char(&... lits)[Ns]) {
    auto result = std::array<char, ((Ns-1) + ... + 1)>{};
    std::ranges::copy(std::views::join(std::array{std::string_view{lits, Ns-1}...}),
                      std::begin(result));
    return result;
}

constexpr char snippet1[] = "some text1";
constexpr char snippet2[] = "some text2";

std::string s = strlit_cat("some text", snippet1, "some more", snippet2).data();
```

The function will also work for literals with embedded null characters and returns the string as a `std::array` of `char`. The construction of `s` however will not work with embedded null characters, but neither does it in the example from your question.

This can also be made more practically usable by wrapping the `std::array` into a fixed-length string class replicating the interface of `std::string` (as far as it makes sense) and a conversion operator to `std::string`.

Comment: This illustrates that C++ compiler is not able to simply concat constant text like the C++ preprocessor can. My question is why can it not?

Comment: @Abazoo There is no builtin functionality for that at runtime either. That is inherited from C. I doubt that anybody would want to add such a feature to the core language. Instead it would be considered a library feature now. `std::string` cannot be used for that because it is arbitrary-length and therefore requires dynamic allocation. There is no other suitable string type in the standard library and `std::string` was designed before doing almost anything at compile-time at the language level was possible. It wasn't designed with that in mind.

Comment: @Abazoo It is however not that hard to define a fixed-length string type and overload its `operator+` so that it will work as you expect (together with a user-defined literal to turn the string literals into this new type). Maybe something like this will be added to the standard library at some point, but standardization is often quite slow.